# How can I remotely determine if a USB3.0 device is plugged into a USB3.0 port?

Tags: windows-8.1, usb-3

The easy answer to this would be "ask the person who put your memory stick into your remote PC to remove it, and put it back into a blue one".

But that person is now heading off to work elsewhere for 2-3 hours. I want to know if it is worth disturbing them to come back and make my life easier. Is there any way I (at the remote end) can tell if a USB3.0 device is plugged into a USB3.0 port... solely using tools you can find on a Windows 8.1 system?

Comment: What sort of remote access? Is the person someone you can talk through commands?

Comment: In the end I found a workaround for what I was trying to do... and got a message to the person who assured me that they knew to put a USB3.0 device into a blue jack :-) But I'd still think it's a question I'd like to be able to answer in future. I was remoting via LogMeIn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run MMC.exe, select "File"->"Add Snapins" (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) and add Device Manager. Now you get a dialog to slect if you want to run this on your local device or a remote one. Select here you remote device and finish.

Now click on "view" and select "devices by connection" and expand all entries. Now look under the USB devices if the USB device is listed under a USB 3.0 Hub:

[image]

In my case the USB mouse and an USB 3.0 disk are both running at USB 3.0 ports.

If you see the device under USB Enhanced Hub, the device is connect to an USb 2.0 port

Comment: Tried it... but none of the Device Manager entries expand like you show. At least not for me on either of the two Win8 machines I have access to.

Comment: Try this tool: http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html

Comment: Between your answer and your comment, I'm accepting the answer - I think it looks like it is going to give enough people enough options - thanks. In the end (as noted in comment to question) I ended up getting the answer courtesy of the guy on site.

Comment: You have to go in display and change this. Should be "By connection" in english or alike. But I disagree with the method. It is not relevant.
I am trying to find a software-based method to determine if my devices are plugged to 2.0 or 3.0 ports and on my frontpanel I have 4 USB 3.0 ports. However 2 of them are actually USB 2.0 and no matter where I plug my device they are displayed under 3.0 extensible thing.
I have AIDA64 license and it also displays under USB 3.0 extensible thingy though it is not true.